# Problemas con marcas de clase en objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

Tengo dos botones asociados (button1 y button2) a un objeto que he definido y me gustaría aplicar el efecto "hover" mediante CSS (ya que me parece mas fácil mediante marcas de clase) para que no aparezcan los botones hasta que pases el ratón por encima de ellos.

He aplicado las marcas de clase "button1" y "button2" a cada botón, sin embargo no consigo dar el efecto "hover".

Adjunto el objeto definido con las marcas de clase y el archivo CSS que tengo asociado:

```
var ejemplo = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.define('ejemplo', {
position: {x: 150, y: 50},
size: {width: 80, height: 40},
attrs: {
'.body': {'ref-width': '100%', 'ref-height': '100%', stroke: '#000'},
image: {'xlink:href': 'bombilla.jpg'},
'.button1': {
  cursor: 'pointer', 
  ref: '.body', 
  refWidth: '100%', 
  refHeight: '100%', 
  refX: '100%', 
  refY: '-10%',
  'r': 7,
  event: 'eliminar',
  fill: '#C0392B',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1
},
'.button2': {
  cursor: 'pointer', 
  ref: '.body', 
  refWidth: '150%', 
  refHeight: '150%', 
  refX: '0%', 
  refY: '-10%',
  'r': 7,
  event: 'rotar',
  fill: 'blue',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 1
},
'.buttonLabel1': {
  pointerEvents: 'none', 
  refX: '100%', 
  refY: '-10%', 
  textAnchor: 'middle', 
  textVerticalAnchor: 'middle', 
  text: 'X',
  fill: 'white',
  fontSize: 8,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
},
'.buttonLabel2': {
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  refX: '0%',
  refY: '-10%',
  textAnchor: 'middle',
  textVerticalAnchor: 'middle', 
  text: 'G', 
  fill: 'white',
  fontSize: 8,
  fontWeight: 'bold' 
  }
}
}, {

markup: [
'<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><image class="body"/></g>',
'<circle class="button1"/><circle class="button2"/>',
'<text class="buttonLabel1"/><text class="buttonLabel2"/>',
'</g>',

]. join(''),
```

El archivo CSS es el siguiente:

```
circle.button1.button2 {
/* Enable interacting with inputs only. */
pointer-events: auto;
}

circle.button1.button2 {
color: white;
border: none;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 20px;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
text-align: middle;
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: -15px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}
circle.button1.button2:hover {
background-color: black;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal para no aplicar este efecto?¿Alguien tiene otra idea alternativa para aplicar el mismo efecto por ejemplo con "mouseover"?

Muchas gracias.

Pd: estoy utilizando librerias ***joint y jquery***

Comment: Podrás mostrar el html donde están esos dos botones?

Comment: Los botones están asociados a círculos en las marcas de clase y que están asociados a un objeto DOM, no son botones hmtl como tal.

Comment: Tienes dos botones uno con la clase button1 y otro con la clase button2, o dos botones ámbos con las clases button1 y button2?

Comment: Tengo una clase para cada botón, <circle class="button1"/><circle class="button2"/>, un circulo con clase button1 y otro circulo con clase button2